# Monoid instance of a tuple in Scala

Tags: scala, purescript, scala-3

I'm trying to convert [purecript-incremental](https://github.com/paf31/purescript-incremental-functions/blob/master/src/Data/Incremental.purs#L58) to Scala 3.1.0. The file linked to above is what I'm trying first. So far I have this:

```scala
trait Patch[T0, T1] extends cats.kernel.Monoid[T1]:
  def combine(x: T1, y: T1): T1
  def empty: T1
  def patch(x: T0, y: T1): T0

trait Diff[T0, T1] extends Patch[T0, T1]:
  def combine(x: T1, y: T1): T1
  def empty: T1
  def patch(x: T0, y: T1): T0
  def diff(x: T0, y: T0): T1

type Change = [T] =>> T

def fromChange[T0, T1](patch: Patch[T0, T1])(using change: Change[T0] => T1) = ???
def toChange[T0, T1](patch: Patch[T0, T1])(using change: T1 => Change[T0]) = ???
```

I'm a little confused on the Monoid instances that the code is using because they don't seem to be in that file nor imported. When implementing the patchUnit and diffUnit, I created this:

```scala
given UnitPatch: Patch[Unit, Unit] with
  def combine(x: Unit, y: Unit): Unit = empty
  def empty: Unit = ()
  def patch(x: Unit, y: Unit): Unit = ()

given UnitDiff: Diff[Unit, Unit] with
  def combine(x: Unit, y: Unit): Unit = UnitPatch.combine(x, y)
  def empty: Unit = UnitPatch.empty
  def patch(x: Unit, y: Unit): Unit = UnitPatch.patch(x, y)
  def diff(x: Unit, y: Unit): Unit = ()
```

Here I assume the Monoid instance for Unit is as is above. The trouble comes when I try to implement the instances for Tuples as demonstrated. What is an empty Tuple? Is combining tuples tuples within a tuple or a Tuple4? Is Unit is Purescript different than Unit in Scala?

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/purescript/purescript-tuples/blob/d4fe8ffe9e8c512111ee0bc18a6ba0fd056a6773/src/Data/Tuple.purs#L53) are PureScript instances for tuple. An empty pair is a pair of empties. Combining two pairs means combining their respective elements.

Comment: Oh, and yes, the instances are imported. [Here](https://github.com/paf31/purescript-incremental-functions/blob/096930c94bdaede2a6fb83669065ccf7bc042f7e/src/Data/Incremental.purs#L24) is the line that imports the instances.